# Associated Legendre/Gegenbauer functions with complex degree at larger order

Tags: harmonic-analysis, special-functions, asymptotics

I am interested in approximating the associated Legendre function (also known as conical function)
\begin{equation}
P_{-1/2 + i p}^{\frac{2-N}{2}}(x)
\end{equation} when $N \to \infty$. The real parameters $x >1$ and $p>0$ are otherwise unconstrained. This function appears in the study of harmonic analysis on hyperboloid $\mathbb{H}_{N}$ and is closely related to the Gegenbauer function
\begin{equation}
C_{-\frac{N-1}{2} +ip}^{\frac{N-1}{2}}(x)
\end{equation}
Is anything known about $N\to \infty$ approximations of these functions?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this is useful: http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0205065